# Problems with Multiviews and redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently deactivate the Multiview option in my htaccess file.
It did the job perfectly, but we also use an external application that call a link with the extension file (http://example.com/export_me?mode=csv&id=3)
So the link does not work anymore and i want to use a rewrite rule to correct this error (i do not have access to the application)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^export_me?mode=(.*)&id=(.*)\$
RewriteRule (.*) export_me.php?mode=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

But i still have a 404 error.

Can anyone help me ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ export_me.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply:

```
RewriteRule ^export_me$ /export_me.php [L]
```

The query string will get appended automatically. You can't match against the query string in the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable, only the `%{QUERY_STRING} variable.